# Centered lineheaders with classicthesis package

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters, classicthesis

I began to use the `classicthesis` package which is very close to a word theme I used to work with before.

The package is configured like that :

```
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
```

The only thing I miss to have a full replacement of my word template is centered titles. How could I personalise the package to center all titles.

Comment: You mean all chapter titles or do you also want to center titles for lower sectional units such as section, subsections,...?

Answer (score 3):

With the `linedheaders` package option, `classicthesis` formats chapter titles using

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
        {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
        {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]
```

so all you have to do is to change `\raggedright` to `\centering`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
        {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
        {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\centering\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If you want all sectional units titles (down to `\paragraph`) centered:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
        {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
        {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\centering\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]
    \titleformat{\section}
        {\centering}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    % subsections
    \titleformat{\subsection}
        {\centering}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}
    % subsubsections
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
        {\centering}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}        
    % paragraphs
    \titleformat{\paragraph}
        {\normalfont\normalsize\centering}{\theparagraph}{0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}    


\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test section}
\subsubsection{A test section}
\paragraph{A test paragraph}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

For `\subparagraph`, which `classicthesis` doesn't modify, you could use something like

```
  %subparagraphs
\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\small\itshape\centering}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Section titles are not centered.

Comment: @egreg I know. It wasn't clear to me if this was also desired, so I asked the OP in a comment to the question.

Comment: @egreg In any case, I added the code for other sectional units.

Comment: My first thought was: `\renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\centering}` but then ... Ah, classicthesis messes with KOMA-script.